# How can I check the intersection from a line layer?

Tags: qgis-2.18

I have a line layer which represent streets and I would like to know where a line is not connected to other in their nodes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to find where the lines are like the two first images automatically, I need all the lines connected, if there's a plugin that do this or other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to identify the unconnected nodes or just snap them (similar to the integrate tool in ArcGIS), so I assumed you just want to connect the nodes to get rid of topology errors. The following is a solution.

Try the GRASS v.clean tool: **Processing > Toolbox > GRASS > Vector > v.clean**

[image]

1. Select your layer
2. Input feature type: line
3. Cleaning tools: break,snap,rmdangle
4. Threshold: 0,5,5 (in this case 0 is just a place holder for the break tool, for the other two this is the distance in map units for snapping)
5. Run

#### Results:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

More info here: https://www.geodose.com/2017/10/how-to-clean-topology-error-in-qgis.html

Comment: I want to identify where they are unconnected for connect them, that's right, I want to get rid of topology errors. So you give me a useful  tool,

Thank you very much Hayden.